# Photos directly to dropbox, discarding local copies automatically

Tags: camera, dropbox, instant-upload

Is there a possibility to take photos directly to dropbox?

Currently Dropbox offers the Camera-Upload option, but it doesn't move, but copies files to Dropbox. This still leaves me to delete the local files by hand, hoping that the photos have already been uploaded.

Similiarily there are solutions like FolderSync, but general purpose synchronization software is liable to misconfiguration and increased maintenance requirements compared to special-purpose software.

Ideally I'd like to have a photo app, that doesn't keep local copies of the image, e.g. something like [Cambox](http://www.getcambox.com/) but for Android instead of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're referring to is covered by http://www.uploadcamapp.com/

They accept upload to Google Drive and Dropbox. Sadly, as of writing this, not OneDrive/365

I also don't know what happens if the service is down / no internet (does it sync later etc)